# Why do HTML comment delimiters not work within HTML style tags?

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS and HTML. I am using an external stylesheet and a "style" element within the HTML to override the external stylesheet.

My question is: when I put an HTML comment inside the "style" element, then the style does not override the external CSS. However, when I use CSS comments inside the "style" element then it does work. HTML comments belong inside HTML and the "style" element is still HTML, so **why do the HTML comments inside the "style" element cause the overrides to fail?**

For example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            <!-- body{background:#eee;} -->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

The above example demonstrates the odd behavior of applying the style in spite of the comment tags.

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/UyXhF/) (tested in Chrome 16.0.912.75 Windows 7)

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: I'm not sure an example is needed... The question stated simply is "Why do HTML comment delimiters not work within HTML style tags?"

Comment: yes, what joseph said, sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS is not a markup language. The style block inside your HTML page is an autonomous piece of code. Similar to javascript inside script block. Its not HTML. So HTML comments are not technically comments inside style block.

Answer (score 5):

Use /* Style */ for Style Commenting and the above for HTML.

Comment: James's answer is correct:
/* comment * / is CSS and should be used inside the style tags.
<!-- comment --> is html and should be used inside html.

If you define a javascript tag with HTML you also have to use /* */ and // for comments. Remember that you're defining alternate piece of code. You wouldn't put html tags inside style and script either would you? :)

Also you should use external CSS to overrule the internal CSS. Not the other way around. It makes no sense cascade wise.